# Raspberry Pi is not booting when the GPIO extension board is plugged in

Tags: boot-issues

I am brand new to Raspberry Pi and don't have much of a background in electronics, so this might be a stupid question, but can someone explain how to use a GPIO extension board in the most basic terms possible? I know you're not supposed to move stuff around on the breadboard when the Raspberry Pi is on when you aren't using an extension board--does that rule apply if you are using the extension board?

I have a kit that came with an extension board, but when the ribbon cable is plugged in to the Pi, it won't boot. The red light comes on but the green light does nothing. Any ideas why this is happening? It boots normally if I unplug the ribbon cable.

Comment: What model Pi and extension board. And are you sure you plugged the board / ribbon cable the right way around?

Comment: Post a photo of what you have and how it is wired. Best to connect anything to/from the GPIO or breadboard when the power is off otherwise you risk damaging the Pi and or components.